# How can I convert list to DataFrame, where items of list will act as column in DataFrame?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

Suppose, I have a list like bellow:

```
L =[
    [11, ['Blue','Green','Yellow'] , 1],
    [21, ['White','Green','Brown'] , 0],
    [31, ['Orange','Yellow']       , 0],
    [41, ['White','Orange','Brown'], 1],
   ] ^           ^^^                 ^
     Id         Colors              vote
```

How can I convert this list to a DataFrame where colors are columns too.

```
     Id      Blue    Green    Yellow    White    Brown    Orange    vote
0    11      1       1        1         0        0        0         1   
1    21      0       1        0         1        1        0         0
2    31      0       0        1         0        0        1         0 
3    41      0       0        0         1        1        1         1
```

Here, df[Id][color] denotes whether color is present in Id or not.

I think, I can do this in iterative way. Is there any simplest way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one (iterative way) to do it, not sure how to do it vectorized.

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

L = [
    [11, ['Blue','Green','Yellow'] , 1],
    [21, ['White','Green','Brown'] , 0],
    [31, ['Orange','Yellow']       , 0],
    [41, ['White','Orange','Brown'], 1],
]

colors = set(chain(*(row[1] for row in L)))
def row2obj(row):
    obj = {c: int(c in row[1]) for c in colors}
    obj['id'] = row[0]
    obj['vote'] = row[2]
    return obj

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(row2obj(row) for row in L)
```

Comment: Is it feasible to apply your techniques when no_row=1600000 and no_colors=230000?

Comment: Not sure, need to time and see. However a DataFrame with 230,000 columns does not seem to be a good idea anyway. Maybe use sparse objects (either DataFrame or scipy.sparse). A "back of the envelope" calculation (assuming int is 8 bytes) you get `(1600000* 230000*8)/1000000000 = 2944` GB.